# Splitting a string at question mark, exclamation mark, or period

Tags: php, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string at a question mark, an exclamation mark, or a period using preg_split, but I've ran into a problem. Instead of splitting at the question mark, it split the string way before that. Please take a look at my code:

```
<?php

    $input = "Why will I have no money? Because I spent it all";
    $input = preg_split( "/ (?|.|!) /", $input ); 
    $input = $input[0];
    echo $input;

?>
```

**Expected results:**

> Why will I have no money

**Actual results:**

> Why will

Comment: `?` and `.` are extra caracters in regex so they need to be escaped `"/ (\\?|\\.|!) /"`

Comment: @mmm I just escaped the question mark and the period. Now it's returning the whole string instead.

Comment: your pattern is `[space][char][space]` though

Comment: Using a character class - `"/[?.!]/"` - makes this simpler as none of those characters have special meaning in context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the special regex characters (`.` and `?`) and remove the spaces.

```
<?php
$input = "Why will I have no money? Because I spent it all";
    $input = preg_split( "/(\?|\.|!)/", $input ); 
print_r($input);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/422337

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Why will I have no money
    [1] =>  Because I spent it all
)
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/zK7cK7/1

Comment: I think this is the second time today you answered one of my questions right! Good job, Chris! You're on a roll! xD

Comment: This is only my first answer for you (...I think?) I edited an unformatted answer on your previous question today.

Comment: Oh. Thought I saw your name sometimes earlier today.